# why doesnt my htaccess allow for multiple rules

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering why my htaccess would not allow for multiple rules? Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Basically I wanted to add a 404 rule. Here is the code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://xxxxxx/404.php
```

Well basically I can not add all of the together in one htaccess file. Here is the code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://xxxxxx/404.php
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

That code above will not work all together. Why is that?

Comment: `That code above will not work` What exactly is not working, can you clarify?

Comment: I guess since its already redirects for .php files it will not redirect on 404...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because basically you are doing two times the same thing in the .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://xxxxxx/404.php
```

The ErrorDocument redirects to 404 in case the requested page is not found. The two RewriteConds `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` plus the RewriteRule will do exactly the same, they will redirect if the request file was not found - in your case they are redirecting to index.php.

So you can try either of the two following:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the URL is being treated as a string, to let it know it's a path you should add a slash at the beginning

try this and see if it works

`ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`